# error : Query Of Queries syntax error

Tags: sql, coldfusion, coldfusion-10

```
<cfquery name="result" datasource="Training">
        select  TE.firstname,TE.lastname,TD.deparmentname,TE.salary,TE.DateOfBirth
        from TEmployee as TE 
        inner join Tdepartment as TD
        on TE.departmentID=TD.departmentID
        where 1 = 1
        <cfif isdefined('form.fname') AND len(form.fname) gt 0 >
        AND TE.FirstName Like  '#Form.fname#%'
        </cfif>
        <cfif isdefined('form.lname') AND len(form.lname) gt 0>
        and TE.LastName Like '#Form.lname#%'
        </cfif>
        <cfif isdefined('form.dept') AND form.dept neq 0>
        and TD.DeparmentName='#form.dept#'
        </cfif>

        <cfif isdefined('form.salary') AND ListLen(Form.salary,'-') EQ 2>
        and TE.salary between #ListGetAt(Form.salary,1,'-')# AND #ListGetAt(Form.salary,2,'-')#
        </cfif>

        <cfif isdefined('form.hidetxt') AND Len(form.hidetxt) GT 0>
            order by #form.hidetxt# 
        </cfif>
    </cfquery>
     <cfdump var="#result#">
            <cfoutput>
            <cfquery dbtype="query" name="detail"> 
                select top 2 * 
                  FROM result
                  WHERE 1=1
                        <cfif isdefined('form.hidetxt') AND Len(form.hidetxt) GT 0>
                                  order by #form.hidetxt# 

                        </cfif>
            </cfquery>
      </cfoutput>
      <cfdump var="#detail#">
```

Error in top 2 . but this query is working in database . what mistake i did in this . in second query error occured in  "select top 2 * ". what to write for that

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the down-vote here..?

Comment: Nothing to do with your error, but you should never use raw `form` values in a database query (or any values supplied by the client) because it exposes your database to sql injection. Instead use [cfqueryparam](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ColdFusion/9.0/CFMLRef/WSc3ff6d0ea77859461172e0811cbec22c24-7f6f.html).

Answer (score 4):

`TOP` is not part of the SQL implementation of QoQ. Use the `maxrows` attribute on the `<cfquery>` tag.